# Discord.py bot only responding to one command

Tags: python, discord.py

Heres my code, it's only responding to the *b command even though the *m *h and *a commands are all pretty much the same. I checked the imagur links and its not that. I originally only had the *m command and it worked fine and then I added the other commands and it's just not responding to any of the commands but the *b command.

```
import discord
import os
import random

client = discord.Client()

anyphotos = [<just a bunch of imagure links in a list>]
mphotos = [<also just a bunch of imagur links in a list>]
bphotos = [<even more imagur links in a list>]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('*h'):
        await message.channel.send("hello!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('*a'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(anyphotos))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('*m'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(mphotos))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('*b'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(bphotos))

client.run('<token>')
```

Comment: You've redefined `on_message` 4 times, only the last one is considered. You can refactor all 4 into one function or use the `commands` extension

Comment: Combine the events or switch to actual commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one on_message but you can combine all of what you have into 1

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('*h'):
        await message.channel.send("hello!")
    if message.content.startswith('*a'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(anyphotos))
    if message.content.startswith('*m'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(mphotos))
    if message.content.startswith('*b'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(bphotos))
```

Comment: You should also tell why there is a problem if you submit the answer

Comment: Ah ok I will add that in now @Xyndra